# Type casting back to a user defined Object in Java

Tags: java

I hope you are all safe and healthy. I'm having a problem with typecasting in java. I have a Card object that has a name and number of type String and int respectively. After getting the name and number of the created object, it seems I cannot return the string back to the same Card object. Is it possible to typecast back to the same card object here? Thanks

```
package app;

public class Card {

    private String cardName;
    private int cardNumber;

    /**
     * This is the Constructor of the class Card that helps to create an object of Card, it has two arguments
     *
     * @param cardName   of type String, which indicates the name of the card e.g. Cross.
     * @param cardNumber of type int, which indicates the number of the card e.g. 10.
     */
    public Card(String cardName, int cardNumber) {
        this.cardName = cardName;
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    }

    /**
     * This method will get the name of a Card object.
     *
     * @return Returns a String.
     */
    public String getCardName() {

        return cardName;
    }

    /**
     * This method will get the number of a Card object.
     *
     * @return Returns an integer.
     */
    public int getCardNumber() {

        return cardNumber;
    }
}
```

```
package app;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Card card = new Card("Circle", 10);
        System.out.println("card before type cast: "+card);

        String cardString = card.getCardName() + " " + card.getCardNumber();
        System.out.println("cardString: "+cardString);

//        String cardStringName = cardString.split(" ")[0];
//        int cardStringNumber = Integer.parseInt(cardString.split(" ")[1]);

        Card cardd = ((Card) cardString); // Error message here: Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.lang.String' to 'app.Card'
        System.out.println("card after type cast: "+cardd);
    }
}
```

**Output:**
Error:(16, 30) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to app.Card

Comment: Did you read the error message? Why would you expect that a `String` should be able to be cast back to a `Card`?

Answer (score 0):

Type casting cannot "return the string back to the same Card object" -- type casting does something very different. If you want to update the name of an existing Card object, you need to add a "setter method" to the Card class:

```
public void setCardName(String newName) {
    cardName = newName;
}
```

After you have done this, you can call this method to update the name in `main`:

```
card.setCardName(cardString);
```